# Change name APK Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I created an app in the android studio called eCoding.  However, when I compile and pass the APK file to my phone, the name that appears is FolioReader.  I have already changed the string package, the project name and it remains the same name... Someond to help me?

Comment: check gradle file

Comment: Hi @blend02 can you share your `android manifest.xml` and `strings.xml` so we can check if their resources are updated, you can also check if `FolioReader` is not hardcoded into the code.

Comment: Hey, this is my code https://www23.zippyshare.com/v/pcuGlmkd/file.html

Answer (score 1):

- Please change the **android:label** field in your application **AndroidManifest.xml**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change app_name from Strings file in resources directory.